# How to check if there is already a record from this month in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose this is the my table (postgreSQL):

```
datecolumn a           b       c
 DATE      INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
01.02.17   1           5       7
01.02.16   5           7
02.02.17   5
30.01.17   8
```

I want to write a query which takes `CURRENT_DATE` compare it to `datecolumn` and shows all records which are from this month & year

So for `CURRENT_DATE` (which today is 02.02.17) the expected result is:

```
datecolumn a b c
01.02.17   1 5 7
02.02.17   5
```

I know I can do:

```
select *
from tab
where extract(month from current_date) = extract(month from datecolumn) and
extract(year from current_date) = extract(year from datecolumn)
```

but I'm wondering if there isn't something that is simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()`

```
select *
from tab
where date_trunc('month', datecolumn) = date_trunc('month', current_date);
```